# Echo XML element value and attribute value of array

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Consider the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <product code="WERGTR">
    </product>
    <product code="HERGGFH">
    </product>
    <product code="NYTERBT">
    </product>
    <product code="NUYRTHT">
    </product>
    <misc>
        <copyrightHTML>Somo stuff</copyrightHTML>
        <categoryLink name="Attr1">http://www.example.com/val1</categoryLink>
        <categoryLink name="Attr2">http://www.example.com/val2</categoryLink>
        <categoryLink name="Attr3">http://www.example.com/val3</categoryLink>
        <categoryLink name="Attr4">http://www.example.com/val4</categoryLink>
    </misc>
</catalog>
```

How can I echo each `<categoryLink>` element? Displaying its value and attribute `name` value?

I've tried using

```
$pricesDatabase = "http://www.example.com/database.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($pricesDatabase) or die("Couldn't create database.xml");

foreach($xml->children() as $links) { 
    echo $links->categoryLink['name'];
    echo "<br>"; 
}
```

But doesn't work, it simply shows nothing.

The result I'm looking for could be as below:

```
$key . ": value: " . $value . ", name: " . $nameValue
```

So...

```
[0]: value: http://www.example.com/val1, name: Attr1
[1]: value: http://www.example.com/val2, name: Attr2
[2]: value: http://www.example.com/val3, name: Attr3
[3]: value: http://www.example.com/val4, name: Attr4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the output is:

```
<br><br><br><br>Attr1<br>
```

`$xml` is associated with the document element node `catalog`. Its children would be `product` and `misc`. The first four '
' are from the `product` nodes, the last is the misc nodes. You're accessing the first `categoryLink` child and its attribute `name`.

```
foreach($xml->misc->categoryLink as $link) { 
    echo $link['name'], ', ', $link;
    echo "\n"; 
}
```

Or using Xpath:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('misc/categoryLink') as $link) { 
    echo $link['name'], ', ', $link;
    echo "\n"; 
}
```

SimpleXMLElement objects behave different depending how they are used, you can iterate over several nodes with the same name, access the first of the list or cast it to string to get the text content.

Comment: Thank you dude. I was having some problems with my code/answer, and decided to try yours. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured how to:

1.- Get the value of `name` attribute for each `<categoryLink>` element:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//misc/categoryLink/@name') as $nameAttr) {
    echo $nameAttr . "<br>"; 
}
```

2.- Get the value of each `<categoryLink>` element:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//misc/categoryLink') as $linkVal) {
    echo $linkVal . "<br>"; 
}
```

The downside is I haven't figured out how to output both values in each line.